Flutter Google Map Current and Live Location
I am using google_maps_flutter to show Map,and dont want to use any other package***, I want to access it without any package as rapido and others using.
My Code.
final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );  

GoogleMap(
              onTap: (argument) {
                print("hello $argument");
              },
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _controller.complete(controller);
              },
              onCameraMove: (position) {
                print("hello ${position.bearing}");
              },
            ),

Please help me with it.

I want to print LatLng when clicked on
myLocationButtonEnabled button.
Currently its marker is moving on location change, so I want to keep printing those changed LatLng.

